# Rating my android app

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I would like to create a popup in my Android app to offer to the user going to the market to vote my app. The case is, to do this I actually need the 'id' play store is going to give me for my app... but if I didn't uploaded it yet, how can I know now that I'm developing it?

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Play doesn't "assign" random ids to apps. The id is the unique package name of your app, which you choose, so you will know it.

For example:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana

Your app will be:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your.package.name

This will be the package you have defined in the `manifest.xml` of your app.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the package name as Google Play will generate a Play Store link based on the package name of your app.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    //Try Google play
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=[package]"));
    if (MyStartActivity(intent) == false) {
        //Market (Google play) app seems not installed, let's try to open a webbrowser
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?[package]"));
        if (MyStartActivity(intent) == false) {
            //Well if this also fails, we have run out of options, inform the user.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Could not open Android market, please install the market app.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Source: [Android: How to create a “Rate this app” button](http://martin.cubeactive.com/android-how-to-create-a-rank-this-app-button/)